# Unable to add an object to a jComboBox; addItem(...) method only accepts String

Tags: java, netbeans, java-8

I have problem in my Java application. Namely, I am getting an error when trying to add an object to a jComboBox.

```
incompatible types: Radnik cannot be converted to String
```

Where `Radnik` is the name of the class I'm trying to add.

This happened to me before, and it seems to be a problem with IDE or JDK, 'cause it seems to happen only in the app I'm working on, but when I do the same thing in another app, it works fine.
I'm working in Netbeans' latest version and JDK 1.8

I don't think I need any additional libraries for that, and my `Radnik` class has it's `toString()` method overriden.

The code where I try to add it to a combo box:

```
private void popuniComboR(List<Radnik> lr){
    jcmbRadnik.removeAllItems();
    for (Radnik r : lr) {
        jcmbVrstaPos.addItem(r);
    }
}
```

This gives me an error.

Comment: It's really hard to say what the problem is without more context. E.g. what is the definition of `jcmbVrstaPos`?

Comment: @radoh `jcmbVrstaPos` is the name of my combo box. `Radnik` is a POJO, a class representing a worker.

Comment: I get that. But how is it defined? as `JComboBox<String>`? or...? Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm kinda new to asking questions. So I created a form and added a jComboBox in designer mode. It _is_ there. And I try to add an object inside of a private form method. I found a workaround by putting the Id of the object into the combo box and then redefining the equals() method of the object so I can iterate through the list of objects (which I get from a database) and then get the whole object that mathes that Id.

Comment: I have no idea how designer mode in netbeans work, but you should be able to tell what type `jcmbVrstaPos`. That's kind of the most basic thing. Try CTRL+left clicking the variable, it should take you to the variable definition...

Comment: `private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jcmbRadnik;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, change the definition of your combobox to, so it is easier to interact with:

```
private javax.swing.JComboBox<Radnik> jcmbRadnik;
```

Alternatively, you could work with String combobox, but then you'll need to convert the `r` to `String`.

```
jcmbVrstaPos.addItem(r.toString());
```

Comment: Boolseye! I didn't even consider the <String> that was standing next to my combo box declaration.